# How to plot a 3D interactive Plot with 1 million+ records with Latitude, Longitude and Altitude Points

Tags: python, python-3.x

1. I know in matplotlib but it doesn't support Zoom and other interactions.
2. I have used Plotly its having good interactive visualization but it
   supports for only 150k records.

The data looks like this

```
Latitude, Longitude, Altitude
40.41,  -104.81,    231.8
40.42   ,-104.82,   231.338528
40.43   ,-104.83,  230.877056
40.44   ,-104.84,   230.415584
40.45   ,-104.85,   229.954112
40.46   ,-104.86,   229.49264
40.47   ,-104.87,   229.031168
```

Comment: Please read the [SO guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), especially #4: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow ".

Comment: Please don't use Indian words like "lakh" here. We're not all from India.